# Prediction vs. model stability in inner and outer loop of repeated nested cross validation

Tags: cross-validation, predictive-models, standard-error, overfitting, mse

Imagine I want to optimize some hyperparameters and get an estimation of the generalization error to compare different prediction models. I use a nested k-fold cross validation to avoid data leakage and repetitions to test inner and outer stability.

So I get a repeated nested k-fold cross validation with:

1) Number of repetitions outer loop = OR

2) Number of folds in outer loop = OF

3) Number of repetitions inner loop = IR

4) Number of folds in inner loop = IF

5) Number of possible hyperparameter combinations for hyperparameter optimization = HP (for example if there are 2 hyperparameters with each 5 possible values then HP = 25 if we use a gridsearch)

6) number of observations = 43

The repetitions just use different splits for train/test set (outer loop) and train/validation set (inner loop). This is to see what the effect of datasplits is on the error.

The possible hyperparameter combinations are tested with the same repetitions (data splits) to have a fair comparison. So HP can also be seen as the number of repetitions of the whole inner loop but with different hyperparameter combinations.

Assume that every observation is used once in the test set of one complete cross validation. So each observation is used 1 * OR times as test set in the outer loop and  (OF-1) * OR * IR *1 * HP times as test set in the inner loops. Because each observation is used (OF-1) * OR times as train dataset in the outer loop and 1*IR times for each hyperparameter combination.

This results in a total of (OR * OF) * (HP¨* (IR * IF)) + OR * OF  different models. HP * (IR * IF) models in 1 inner loop which is repeated for each outer fold OF and outer repetition OR. The outer models are trained with the best hyperparameter combination of the inner loop and the train+validation data of the inner loop as their training data. Resulting in OR * OF models extra.

I know this method is computational not optimal but it is used to get a complete picture.

---

## Model Stability

### outer stability

#### Method 1

The *best* hyperparameter combination is chosen for each outer model based on the hyperparameter combination with the lowest MSE in the inner loop. So a total of OR * OF *best* hyperparameter combinations are chosen. These are used to train a new model based on the training data of the outer models (=train+validation of inner loop). So we get OR * OF outer models. Each of these models is tested with their outer test data to calculate the MSE. This results in OR * OF MSE values or estimations of the generalization error. The mean of these OR * OF MSE values gives a good expected value of the generalization error.

$$ Generalization \; error =\overline{MSE} = \frac{Sum(MSE_{1},MSE_{2},...,MSE_{OR*OF})}{OR*OF}$$

But a mean value is not complete without an estimation of its variation so we calculate the standard error which is equal to the standard deviation of the OR * OF MSE values divided by the square root of OR * OF:

$$SE = \frac{SD(MSE_{1},MSE_{2},...,MSE_{OR*OF})}{\sqrt{OR*OF}}$$

Now we have a an estimation of the outer model stability and an estimation of its deviation. This can be used to compare with other models to see which has the best performance.

#### Method 2

There is another way to test the outer stability of the model when the outer loop is repeated. This time we don't use the MSE values of OR * OF models but only the MSE values of the complete cross validation so we have OR MSE values. This results in the mean MSE or generalization error:

$$ Generalization \; error =\overline{MSE} = \frac{Sum(MSE_{1},MSE_{2},...,MSE_{OR})}{OR}$$

This is mathematically equal to the generalization error of method 1. But for the standard error it is not the same:

$$SE = \frac{SD(MSE_{1},MSE_{2},...,MSE_{OR})}{\sqrt{OR}}$$

### Inner stability

The following explanation is for one inner loop but happens in each inner loop. Similar to the outer model stability there are 2 methods.

#### Method 1

The MSE is calculated with the validation dataset for each hyperparameter combination, inner repetition and inner fold resulting in HP*IR*IF MSE values. Now we want to know which hyperparameter combination results in the smallest MSE. This can be done by comparing for each hyperparameter combination the mean MSE value of the inner folds of the inner repetitions. So we get HP mean MSE values, one for each hyperparameter combination. The lowest mean MSE value wins and the corresponding hyperparameter combination goes on to the next round to be used for training the outer model. The mean MSE value for each hyperparametercombination is:

$$\overline{MSE} = \frac{Sum(MSE_{1},MSE_{2},...,MSE_{IR*IF})}{IR*IF}$$

Here we also want to have an estimation of the variation of the mean MSE value for a hyperparameter combination. This is the standard deviation of the IR * IF MSE  values of a hyperparameter combination divided by the square root of IR * IF:

$$SE = \frac{SD(MSE_{1},MSE_{2},...,MSE_{IR*IF})}{\sqrt{IR*IF}}$$

Now we have for each hyperparameter combination an estimate of the MSE value and an estimation of its variation.

#### Method 2

Alternatively we could just like in method 2 of the outer stability use the MSE values of the complete cross validation. This results in IR MSE values for a hyperparameter combination. The mean MSE value for a hyperparameter combination is:

$$\overline{MSE} = \frac{Sum(MSE_{1},MSE_{2},...,MSE_{IR})}{IR}$$

This is equal to the mean MSE in method 1 of the inner stability. Just like in the outer stability is the standard error also different:

$$SE = \frac{SD(MSE_{1},MSE_{2},...,MSE_{IR})}{\sqrt{IR}}$$

---

## Prediction Stability

The model stability is used to see if slightly different datasets will give different best combinations of hyperparameters (inner model stability) and different generalization errors (outer model stability). What if we also want to know information about future predictions? The generalization error gives an estimate of the mean performance but not how much could a single prediction deviate from its actual value.

### Inner stability

When looking at single predictions we need to start with the single prediction errors. A total of  HP * IR * 43 squared errors is calculated in each inner loop so each hyperparameter combination has IR * 43 squared errors (43 is the number of observations and in each complete cross validation each observation is tested once). The mean of these errors is the MSE for a hyperparameter combination:

$$MSE = \frac{Sum(E_{1},E_{2},...,E_{IR*43})}{IR*43}$$

This is equal to the mean MSE in method 1 and 2 of the inner model stability. The standard error however is completely different. Now we want to have a measure of how much a single prediction error can deviate from the mean prediction error:

$$SE = \frac{SD(E_{1},E_{2},...,E_{IR*43})}{\sqrt{IR*43}}$$

### Outer stability

The OR * OF outer models are trained with the best hyperparameter combination from the inner loop. The outer test set gives OR * 43 squared errors. The mean of these squared errors is the generalization error.

$$ Generalization \; error =MSE = \frac{Sum(E_{1},E_{2},...,E_{OR}*43)}{OR*43}$$

This is equal to the generalization error in method 1 and 2 of the outer model stability. But once again the standard error is not the same. We want to have a measure of how much a single prediction error can deviate from the mean prediction error (= generalization error):

$$SE = \frac{SD(E_{1},E_{2},...,E_{OR*43})}{\sqrt{OR*43}}$$

Sorry for the rather long explanation if there is anything unclear or if there are any mistakes please let me know.

My understanding of this model is this: when comparing models (model building techniques actually) you do everything with the measures of method 1 of the model stability. After you compared the models you can retrain the same data with the winning model (best generalization error) and the hyperparameter combination that *won* the most inner loops of that model to create a final model. You have however no estimation of error (mean and standard error) of future predictions  because all the data is already used so any test would be biased.
But here are my questions:

1) What measure is preferred to select the best hyperparameter combination in the inner loop (model stability method 1 or 2 or prediction stability or something else)? More specifically which standard error because the means are the same.

2) what measure is preferred as generalization error? Which standard error, because the means are the same.

3) Can you assume that the generalization error of the repeated nested cross validation will be similar to the final model? It is possible that not all outer models of the repeated nested cross validation have the same hyperparameters so this is maybe not a fair generalization? Or is there an unbiased way to calculate the error of the final model (assume that all data is used for hyperparameter optimization and model comparison)?

4) I would like an estimation of the standard deviation of the error of future predictions for the final model. Should i just use the standard error of the prediction errors of the outer models (outer stability of prediction stability)?

5) follow-up on 3 and 4: When not all inner loops result in the same hyperparameter combination is it better to select only the outer models with the same hyperparameter combinations as the final model to calculate the error of future predictions for the final model(mean and standard error)?

6) it is possible to check for overfitting by comparing the inner MSE with the outer MSE, but again which  standard error should i use to do this?

A more general explanation is also welcome, thank you